# Set focus on web page rather than Firefox debugger after refreshing page

Tags: javascript, firefox, dom-events, firefox-developer-tools

I'm using the default Firefox web developer tools. Firefox 20.0, Mac OS X 10.7.

If I have the developer tools' Debugger panel open (but not focused), and refresh the page, focus goes to the debugger panel rather than the refreshed page. Can I set focus to go to the refreshed page instead?

If I have the Web Console panel open instead, that doesn't steal the focus - ideally I'd like to get the debugger to behave the same way.

My program uses document `keyup` and `keydown` events, and the page needs focus for these to work. Having to click on the page each time is proving surprisingly annoying (it's only a small thing, but it's doubling the amount of work required for each refresh!).

Answer (score 1):

This is still an annoyance, as of Firefox `61.0.2` *(Windows 7)*.

The only workaround I've found is to have Developer Tools set to run in "*Separate window*" mode - instead of docked to the browser, like:

[image: Separate Window Setting]

Comment: It's almost 2022, Firefox `95.0.1`, still have to resort to Chrome to inspect elements without loosing focus (hint: `Rendering` tab, `Emulate a focused page` checkbox). Doesn't seem to be a high priority feature for the Firefox team, does it?

Answer (score -2):

use this on page

```
 <body onload = "window.focus();">
```

Comment: I added this to my HTML file, but the focus still switches to the debugger. Same if I put it at the end of the `window.onload` function.